# Fast reading (by chunk?) and processing of a file with dummy lines at regular interval in R

Tags: r, import

I have a file with regular numeric output (same format) of many arrays, each separated by a single line (containing some info).
For example:

```
library(gdata)
nx = 150 # ncol of my arrays
ny = 130 # nrow of my arrays
myfile = 'bigFileWithRowsToSkip.txt'
niter = 10
for (i in 1:niter) {
  write(paste(i, 'is the current iteration'), myfile, append=T)
  z = matrix(runif(nx*ny), nrow = ny) # random numbers with dim(nx, ny)
  write.fwf(z, myfile, append=T, rownames=F, colnames=F) #write in fixed width format
}
```

With `nx=5` and `ny=2`, I would have a file like this:

```
# 1 is the current iteration
# 0.08051668 0.19546772 0.908230985 0.9920930408 0.386990316
# 0.57449532 0.21774728 0.273851698 0.8199024885 0.441359571
# 2 is the current iteration
# 0.655215475 0.41899060 0.84615044 0.03001664 0.47584591
# 0.131544592 0.93211342 0.68300161 0.70991368 0.18837031
# 3 is the current iteration
# ...
```

I want to read the successive arrays as fast as possible to put them in a single `data.frame` (in reality, I have thousands of them). What is the most efficient way to proceed?

Given the output is regular, I thought `readr` would be a good idea (?). 
The only way I can think of, is to do it manually by chunks in order to eliminate the useless info lines:

```
library(readr)
ztot = numeric(niter*nx*ny) # allocate a vector with final size 
# (the arrays will be vectorized and successively appended to each other)
for (i in 1:niter) {
  nskip = (i-1)*(ny+1) + 1 # number of lines to skip, including the info lines
  z = read_table(myfile, skip = nskip, n_max = ny, col_names=F)
  z = as.vector(t(z))
  ifirst = (i-1)*ny*nx + 1 # appropriate index
  ztot[ifirst:(ifirst+nx*ny-1)] = z
}

# The arrays are actually spatial rasters. Compute the coordinates 
# and put everything in DF for future analysis:
x = rep(rep(seq(1:nx), ny), niter) 
y = rep(rep(seq(1:ny), each=nx), niter) 

myDF = data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z)
```

But this is not fast enough. How can I achieve this faster?

Is there a way to read everything at once and delete the useless rows afterwards?

Alternatively, is there no reading function accepting a vector with precise locations as `skip` argument, rather than a single number of initial rows?

*PS: note the reading operation is to be repeated on many files (same structure) located in different directories, in case it influences the solution...*

---

**EDIT**
The following solution (reading all lines with `readLines` and removing the undesirable ones and then processing the rest) is a faster alternative with `niter` very high:

```
bylines <- readLines(myfile)
dummylines = seq(1, by=(ny+1), length.out=niter)
bylines = bylines[-dummylines] # remove dummy, undesirable lines
asOneChar <- paste(bylines, collapse='\n') # Then process output from readLines
library(data.table)
ztot <- fread(asOneVector)
ztot <- c(t(ztot))
```

Discussion on how to proceed results from the `readLines` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902971/fastest-way-to-convert-a-list-of-character-vectors-to-numeric-in-r)

Comment: can you post few lines of actual file you have in your question

Comment: @Dhawal Kapil the first script is aimed at producing this file to give a reproducible example and the structure is really like mentioned... Anyway, I adapted the example to make it more concrete, does it help?

Comment: okay your code produces a file with `This is iteration 1` written twice in the beginning and 1310 rows of space seperated numbers? what are these numbers. Is each row a separate entity and you want to process them only skipping `This is iteration 1` , `This is iteration 2` and so on?

Comment: No, the code produces a file with `This is iteration 1` written once, then `ny` rows of `nx` space-separated random numbers between 0 and 1 (as `z = matrix(runif(nx*ny), nrow = ny)` suggests), then `This is iteration 2`, then `ny` rows of `nx` numbers, ans so on. Maybe you should delete the generated file and try again? Indeed each *group* of rows is a separate entity that I'd want to process while skipping the `This is iteration X` rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-processing the file with a command line tool (i.e., not in `R`) is actually way faster. For example with `awk`:

```
tmpfile <- 'cleanFile.txt'
mycommand <- paste("awk '!/is the current iteration/'", myfile, '>', tmpfile)
# "awk '!/is the current iteration/' bigFileWithRowsToSkip.txt > cleanFile.txt"
system(mycommand) # call the command from R
ztot <- fread(tmpfile)
ztot <- c(t(ztot))
```

Lines can be removed on the basis of a [pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string-using-sed) or of [indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894986/how-can-i-delete-every-xth-line-in-a-text-file) for example.
This was suggested by @Roland from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902971/fastest-way-to-convert-a-list-of-character-vectors-to-numeric-in-r).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I still understood your problem correctly. Running your script created a file with 1310 lines. With `This is iteration 1or2or3` printed at lines

```
Line 1: This is iteration 1
Line 132: This is iteration 2
Line 263: This is iteration 3
Line 394: This is iteration 4
Line 525: This is iteration 5
Line 656: This is iteration 6
Line 787: This is iteration 7
Line 918: This is iteration 8
Line 1049: This is iteration 9
Line 1180: This is iteration 10
```

Now there is data between these lines that you want to read and skip this 10 strings.

You can do this by tricking `read.table` saying your `comment.char` is "T" which will make `read.table` thinks all lines starting with letter "T" are comments and will skip those.

```
data<-read.table("bigFile.txt",comment.char = "T")
```

this will give you a `data.frame` of `1300` observations with `150` variables.

```
> dim(data)
[1] 1300  150
```

For a non-consisted strings. Read your data with `read.table` with `fill=TRUE` flag. This will not break your input process.

```
data<-read.table("bigFile.txt",fill=TRUE)
```

Your data looks like this

```
> head(data)

          V1          V2           V3         V4          V5        V6        V7
1: 1.0000000          is          the    current   iteration        NA        NA
2: 0.4231829 0.142353335 0.3813622692 0.07224282 0.037681101 0.7761575 0.1132471
3: 0.1113989 0.587115721 0.2960257430 0.49175715 0.642754463 0.4036675 0.4940814
4: 0.9750350 0.691093967 0.8610487920 0.08208387 0.826175117 0.8789275 0.3687355
5: 0.1831840 0.001007096 0.2385952028 0.85939856 0.646992019 0.5783946 0.9095849
6: 0.7648907 0.204005372 0.8512769730 0.10731854 0.299391995 0.9200760 0.7814541
```

Now if you see how the strings are distributed in columns. Now you can simply subset your data set with pattern matching. Matching columns that match these strings. For example

```
library(data.table)
data<-as.data.table(data)
cleaned_data<-data[!(V3 %like% "the"),]

> head(cleaned_data)
          V1          V2           V3         V4          V5        V6        V7
1: 0.4231829 0.142353335 0.3813622692 0.07224282 0.037681101 0.7761575 0.1132471
2: 0.1113989 0.587115721 0.2960257430 0.49175715 0.642754463 0.4036675 0.4940814
3: 0.9750350 0.691093967 0.8610487920 0.08208387 0.826175117 0.8789275 0.3687355
4: 0.1831840 0.001007096 0.2385952028 0.85939856 0.646992019 0.5783946 0.9095849
5: 0.7648907 0.204005372 0.8512769730 0.10731854 0.299391995 0.9200760 0.7814541
6: 0.3943193 0.508373900 0.2131134905 0.92474343 0.432134031 0.4585807 0.9811607
```

Comment: Thanks @Dhawal Kapil, this is a good idea and could have been very helpful, but unfortunately the dummy info lines do *not* start with a unique and consistent character I could use. I adapted the question to show that. Any more general solution?

Comment: @ztl I modified the answer with some suggestions to handle non-consistent string..see if it helps you..