# How to remove every fourth line in a file? Using UNIX commands

Tags: shell, unix, command-line-interface

What's the command which is used to remove every fourth line in a file? As these lines contain garbled characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete every Xth line in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894986/how-can-i-delete-every-xth-line-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
awk 'NR%4 != 0'  filename
```

Comment: What does the garbled content look like? Is it possible that you have an internationalisation issue, instead?